# Is there a way to leave previous messages up while pushing out badge updates?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So imagine this scenario:

10.00: your app pushes a message "Hello"

10.01: your app pushes a badge update with no message out the same device

What happens is that the message dissappears. So if the user didn't see it, it's gone. Is there a way to send a badge notification without clearing any previous messages? I know you can send the message again, but I don't want to spam users who may have already ready the message.

I don't want to have a discussion about the why, simply if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible.  We recommend including badge updates with your alerts, to set it at the same time, but there's no way to **just** update the badge without "overwriting" the alert.

At the same time, however, any message from any other application will also overwrite your earlier alert.

If you include a sound in your APNS payload, the phone will either play the sound or vibrate, so you could at least give the user feedback that a message has been received if you end up needing to do this.